# Tensorflow tf.squeeze cannot squeeze dim[2], expected dimension of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation, resnet

Im trying to build an image segmentation model based on resnet50 with segnet as segmentation model. Im using SparseCategoricalCrossentropy as loss function and RMSprop as optimizer. Im getting an error from my loss function. Does anyone know a fix for this ? I sadly didnt find any solution yet. Thank you in advance!

I get the following error:

```
    File "c:\Users\name\Documents\image-segmentation-keras\env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
...
    File "c:\Users\name\Documents\image-segmentation-keras\env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 885, in sparse_categorical_matches
        y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, [-1])

    ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 608 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,416,608].
```

I try to use a tf.dataset, my prefetchdataset looks like this:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

dataset = {"train": train_dataset, "val": val_dataset}

# -- Train Dataset --#
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE, seed=SEED)
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].repeat()
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset['train'] = dataset['train'].prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

#-- Validation Dataset --#
dataset['val'] = dataset['val'].map(load_image_test)
dataset['val'] = dataset['val'].repeat()
dataset['val'] = dataset['val'].batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset['val'] = dataset['val'].prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

print(dataset['train'])
print(dataset['val'])
```

Output:

```
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 416, 608, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 416, 608, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 416, 608, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 416, 608, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

My model summary looks like this (I had to shrink the model summary because it was too much text for stackoverflow):

```
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 416, 608, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 422, 614, 3)  0          ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 208, 304, 64  9472        ['zero_padding2d[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)  (None, 208, 304, 64  256         ['conv1[0][0]']                  
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)        (None, 208, 304, 64  0           ['bn_conv1[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 103, 151, 64  0           ['activation[0][0]']             
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 res2a_branch2a (Conv2D)        (None, 103, 151, 64  4160        ['max_pooling2d[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn2a_branch2a (BatchNormalizat  (None, 103, 151, 64  256        ['res2a_branch2a[0][0]']         
 ion)                           )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_1 (Activation)      (None, 103, 151, 64  0           ['bn2a_branch2a[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 res2a_branch2b (Conv2D)        (None, 103, 151, 64  36928       ['activation_1[0][0]']           
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn2a_branch2b (BatchNormalizat  (None, 103, 151, 64  256        ['res2a_branch2b[0][0]']  
....

  bn4c_branch2b (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4c_branch2b[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_29 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4c_branch2b[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4c_branch2c (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 1024  263168      ['activation_29[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn4c_branch2c (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 1024  4096       ['res4c_branch2c[0][0]']         
 ion)                           )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 add_9 (Add)                    (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['bn4c_branch2c[0][0]',          
                                )                                 'activation_27[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_30 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['add_9[0][0]']                  
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 res4d_branch2a (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 256)  262400      ['activation_30[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 bn4d_branch2a (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4d_branch2a[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_31 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4d_branch2a[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4d_branch2b (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 256)  590080      ['activation_31[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 bn4d_branch2b (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4d_branch2b[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_32 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4d_branch2b[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4d_branch2c (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 1024  263168      ['activation_32[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn4d_branch2c (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 1024  4096       ['res4d_branch2c[0][0]']         
 ion)                           )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 add_10 (Add)                   (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['bn4d_branch2c[0][0]',          
                                )                                 'activation_30[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_33 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['add_10[0][0]']                 
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 res4e_branch2a (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 256)  262400      ['activation_33[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 bn4e_branch2a (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4e_branch2a[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_34 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4e_branch2a[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4e_branch2b (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 256)  590080      ['activation_34[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 bn4e_branch2b (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4e_branch2b[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_35 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4e_branch2b[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4e_branch2c (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 1024  263168      ['activation_35[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn4e_branch2c (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 1024  4096       ['res4e_branch2c[0][0]']         
 ion)                           )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 add_11 (Add)                   (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['bn4e_branch2c[0][0]',          
                                )                                 'activation_33[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_36 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['add_11[0][0]']                 
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 res4f_branch2a (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 256)  262400      ['activation_36[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 bn4f_branch2a (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4f_branch2a[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_37 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4f_branch2a[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4f_branch2b (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 256)  590080      ['activation_37[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 bn4f_branch2b (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 256)  1024       ['res4f_branch2b[0][0]']         
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 activation_38 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 256)  0           ['bn4f_branch2b[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 res4f_branch2c (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 38, 1024  263168      ['activation_38[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn4f_branch2c (BatchNormalizat  (None, 26, 38, 1024  4096       ['res4f_branch2c[0][0]']         
 ion)                           )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 add_12 (Add)                   (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['bn4f_branch2c[0][0]',          
                                )                                 'activation_36[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 activation_39 (Activation)     (None, 26, 38, 1024  0           ['add_12[0][0]']                 
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 28, 40, 1024  0          ['activation_39[0][0]']          
 D)                             )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 26, 38, 512)  4719104     ['zero_padding2d_2[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (BatchNorm  (None, 26, 38, 512)  2048       ['conv2d[0][0]']                 
 alization)                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D)   (None, 52, 76, 512)  0           ['batch_normalization[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_3 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 54, 78, 512)  0          ['up_sampling2d[0][0]']          
 D)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 52, 76, 256)  1179904     ['zero_padding2d_3[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_1 (BatchNo  (None, 52, 76, 256)  1024       ['conv2d_1[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 104, 152, 25  0          ['batch_normalization_1[0][0]']  
                                6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_4 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 106, 154, 25  0          ['up_sampling2d_1[0][0]']        
 D)                             6)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)              (None, 104, 152, 12  295040      ['zero_padding2d_4[0][0]']       
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_2 (BatchNo  (None, 104, 152, 12  512        ['conv2d_2[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                   8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 208, 304, 12  0          ['batch_normalization_2[0][0]']  
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_5 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 210, 306, 12  0          ['up_sampling2d_2[0][0]']        
 D)                             8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 seg_feats (Conv2D)             (None, 208, 304, 64  73792       ['zero_padding2d_5[0][0]']       
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_3 (BatchNo  (None, 208, 304, 64  256        ['seg_feats[0][0]']              
 rmalization)                   )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)              (None, 208, 304, 10  60008       ['batch_normalization_3[0][0]']  
                                4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 reshape (Reshape)              (None, 63232, 104)   0           ['conv2d_3[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 activation_49 (Activation)     (None, 63232, 104)   0           ['reshape[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 14,920,872
Trainable params: 14,888,360
Non-trainable params: 32,512
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Error happens in keras metrics_utils.py in following function:

```
def sparse_categorical_matches(y_true, y_pred):
  """Creates float Tensor, 1.0 for label-prediction match, 0.0 for mismatch.

  You can provide logits of classes as `y_pred`, since argmax of
  logits and probabilities are same.

  Args:
    y_true: Integer ground truth values.
    y_pred: The prediction values.

  Returns:
    Match tensor: 1.0 for label-prediction match, 0.0 for mismatch.
  """
  reshape_matches = False
  y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
  y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
  y_true_org_shape = tf.shape(y_true)
  y_pred_rank = y_pred.shape.ndims
  y_true_rank = y_true.shape.ndims

  # If the shape of y_true is (num_samples, 1), squeeze to (num_samples,)
  if (y_true_rank is not None) and (y_pred_rank is not None) and (len(
      backend.int_shape(y_true)) == len(backend.int_shape(y_pred))):
    """first error happens in row below"""
    #y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, [-1])
    """your suggestion:"""
    try:
      y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, [-1])
    except ValueError:
      pass


    reshape_matches = True
  y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)

  # If the predicted output and actual output types don't match, force cast them
  # to match.
  if backend.dtype(y_pred) != backend.dtype(y_true):
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, backend.dtype(y_true))
    """after your suggestion next error happens in row below"""
  matches = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())
  if reshape_matches:
    matches = tf.reshape(matches, shape=y_true_org_shape)
  return matches
```

Answer (score 1):

Squeeze removes dimensions of length 1 from the array. If there are no such dimensions it apparently does not fail silently.
I think one solution would be to simply wrap the squeeze in a try except:

```py
try:
   y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, [-1])
except ValueError:
   pass
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and sadly got the following error: `File "c:\Users\name\Documents\image-segmentation-keras\env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 898, in sparse_categorical_matches
        matches = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 608 and 63232 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze, Cast_1)' with input shapes: [?,416,608], [?,63232].`

Comment: could you add the code where this error happens?

Comment: The errros happen in keras metrics_utils.py. I added the the function where the errors happen in my question above, I commented above both lines where errors happen